# Show departmental news on Hub site using filter on news category

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to show the news of departmental site on the Hub site by filtering the news category. Can any one advise how I can apply the filter on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create managed property and map the managed propery to the crawl property category. Please refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema#create-a-new-managed-property

After creating managed property, you could use it in the news web part to apply the filter.

[image]